Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "wkhtmltopdf":
When I am trying to convert a PDF from html using wkhtmltopdf, I am facing the below error.
wkhtmltopdf is already installed in my laptop and I am able to generate using cmd using the same command.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "wkhtmltopdf": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:594)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:418)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:315)
    at com.test.Test.makeAPdf(Test.java:20)
    at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:13)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:158)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
    ... 6 more

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    makeAPdf();
}

public static void makeAPdf() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    Process wkhtml; // Create uninitialized process
    String command = "wkhtmltopdf --enable-local-file-access D://Test//1.html D://Test//output.pdf";//"wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com /Users/Shared/output.pdf"; // Desired command

    wkhtml = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); // Start process
    IOUtils.copy(wkhtml.getErrorStream(), System.err); // Print output to console

    wkhtml.waitFor(); // Allow process to run
}


The app is not in your PATH. Put it there or use the full path. Better also to use ProcessBuilder directly

By the way, I don't think you need double slashes.

You don't need them, single would probably do, but since this is a Windows command, in this case I would turn them into backslashes. String[] command = { "wkhtmltopdf",  "--enable-local-file-access",  "D:\\Test\\1.html", "D:\\Test\\output.pdf" }; Process p = new ProcessBuilder(command).inheritIO().start();
